# wix velo : using a dropdown menu to navigate to another item of a collection

Tags: collections, drop-down-menu, navigation, velo

I created two dynamic pages linked to an "ACTIVITIES" collection.

The 1st is general, it lists all the activities.

The 2nd, ACTIVITIES-Item, details the characteristics of each activity, identified by the field “Title”.

On the ACTIVITIES-Item page, I would like to be able to go directly to another activity, chosen through a dropdown menu, without returning to the ACTIVITIES-All page.

I would actually like to reproduce the menu that exists and works well in the WIX editor. Please, have a look at the attached screenshot.

I have created the field “myUrl” in order to use [wixLocation.to (myUrl)]. This works well with a dropdown menu that I have built myself, but I want this dropdown menu to be built from the “ACTIVITIES” collection.

I have looked for a solution in the velo WIX assistance site, I have searched extensively on the WIX support pages, carried out numerous tests, and look for it in stack overflow forum, but I cannot find a solution.

Is there a modus operandi to do that ?